# Selecting new records by datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select records which have a recdate within the past year

```
$goodate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")-1));
$sqlstmt = "SELECT * FROM #__mytable WHERE id=".$uid." AND recdate > ".$goodate.'"' ;
```

but I'm getting no records.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sqlstmt = "SELECT * FROM #__mytable
            WHERE id=".$uid."
              AND recdate > ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically, the DateTime object is a great tool.

```
       $date = new DateTime();
       $gooddate = $date->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 year'));
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM #__mytable WHERE id=".$uid." AND recdate > ".$goodate->format('Y-m-d').'"';
```

This is assuming your date field is mysql type DATE.  If not, there are similar DateTime methods for outputting unix timestamps, and the `format()` method accepts any formatting string that `date()` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "
select * 
from #__mytable
where 
    id = $uid
    and 
    date_format(recdate, '%Y') = date_format(adddate(curdate(), interval -1 year), '%Y')
"
```